# Loading Cassandra data with SStableloader from different Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, bulk-load

I have two different independent machines running Cassandra and I want to migrate the data from one machine to the other.

Thus, I first took a snapshot of my Cassandra Cluster on machine 1 according to the  [datastax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsSnapShot.html).

Then I moved the data to machine 2, where I'm trying to import it with sstableloader.

As a note: The keypsace (open_weather) and tablename (raw_weather_data) on the machine 2 have been created and are the same as on machine 1.

The command I'm using looks as follows:

```
bin/sstableloader -d localhost "path_to_snapshot"/open_weather/raw_weather_data
```

And then get the following error:

```
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
For input string: "CompressionInfo.db"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CompressionInfo.db"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Descriptor.fromFilename(Descriptor.java:276)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Descriptor.fromFilename(Descriptor.java:235)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.Component.fromFilename(Component.java:120)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTable.tryComponentFromFilename(SSTable.java:160)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader$1.accept(SSTableLoader.java:84)
    at java.io.File.list(File.java:1161)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.openSSTables(SSTableLoader.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:162)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:106)
```

Unfortunately I have no idea why?

I'm not sure if it is related to the issue, but somehow on machine 1 my *.db files are name rather "strange" as compared to the *.db files I already have on machine 2.

*.db files from machine 1:

```
la-53-big-CompressionInfo.db
la-53-big-Data.db
...
la-54-big-CompressionInfo.db
...
```

*.db files from machine 2:

```
open_weather-raw_weather_data-ka-5-CompressionInfo.db
open_weather-raw_weather_data-ka-5-Data.db
```

What am I missing? Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm also open to any other suggestions. The COPY command will most probably not work since it is Limited to 99999999 rows as far as I know.

P.s. I didn't want to create a overly huge post, but if you need any further information to help me out, just let me know.

EDIT:
Note that I'm using Cassandra in the stand-alone mode.

EDIT2:
After installing the same version 2.1.4 on my destination machine (machine 2), I still get all the same error. With SSTableLoader I still get the above mentioned error and with copying the files manually (as described by LHWizard), I still get empty tables after starting Cassandra again and performing a SELECT command.

Regarding the initial tokens, I get a huge list of tokens if I perform node ring on machine 1. I'm not sure what to do with those?

Comment: is the 2nd machine a new node with no other data?

Comment: The second machine has the same keyspaces and tables as the 1st machine. Initially it also had some values in it. I first tried it with the other data inside and then with an empty table. Same result in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

your data is already in the form of a snapshot (or backup). What I have done in the past is the following:

1. install the same version of cassandra on the restore node
2. edit cassandra.yaml on the restore node - make sure that cluster_name and snitch are the same.
3. edit seeds: list and any other properties that were altered in the original node.
4. get the schema from the original node using cqlsh DESC KEYSPACE.
5. start cassandra on the restore node and import the schema. 
   (steps 6 & 7 may not be completely necessary, but this is what I do.)
6. stop cassandra, delete the contents of /var/lib/cassandra/data/*, commitlog/*, and saved_caches/* folders.
7. restart cassandra on the restore node to recreate the correct folders, then stop it
8. copy the contents of the snapshots folder to each corresponding table folder in the restore node, then start cassandra. You probably want to run nodetool repair.

You don't really need to bulk import the data, it's already in the correct format if you are using the same version of cassandra, although you didn't specify that in your original question.

Comment: I actually tried a something similar before without success. That's why I was trying SSTableloader afterwards. Anyway, I retried, following you description with the result data the table is still empty if I perform a SELECT command in cqlsh.
I actually noted that machine 1 has version 2.1.4 where as my destination machine has 2.1.11. Not sure if that might be the reason? 
Also, I'm a bit confused by step 6. If I delete the contents of .../data/, then the keyspace I created in step 4 will be delete again, right? Regarding step 2. the cluster names are the same and I didn't touch anything else.

Comment: yeah, step 6&7 seem unnecessary at this point, although I seem to recall there might have been files in the commitlog folder before any data import. don't forget to change the ownership of all the files to cassandra:cassandra - I found permission errors in system.log when I forgot to do that. I don't know if there is a difference in sstable format between 2.1.4 and 2.1.11. Make sure cassandra is stopped when you copy the files into the new folders. See another example of this technique [here](http://engineering.mydrivesolutions.com/posts/cassandra_nodes_replacement/)

Comment: the one thing I didn't cover was token assignment. In your original cluster, you can find out the token assignment with `nodetool ring`. On the 2nd cluster, edit cassandra.yaml and specify the initial_token with that value.

Comment: first of all, thank you for all your suggestions. Regarding the permission, it shouldn't be an issue since I'm executing Cassandra as root. I changed them anyway, without any effect. Also, not sure if it changes anything, but I probably should have noted, that I'm running Cassandra as a standalone process (rather than service). regarding the initial_token, I'll try it on Monday, since I don't have access to machine 1 right now. My intuition tells me that I might be related to the different naming schemes between the 2 machine. But I don't have enough insight to really know that.